# php does not import variables from another file

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a cloud system with login/register system and mysql, but the problem is that php does not imports the variables i'm including.

Here is my config file:

```
<?php
// Connection details
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "database";
 ?>
```

And my code to include the config file:

```
require("/classes/config.class.php");
```

When i'm trying do echo the variables that are defined in the config it gives this error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: servername in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 2

I'm using xampp on my local computer it has php Version 5.5.30.

EDIT: First lines of php, from comment

```
<?php 
// Include classes require("/classes/user.class.php"); 
require("/classes/password.class.php"); 
// Include configuration require("/classes/config.class.php"); 
echo $servername; echo $username; echo $password; echo $dbname;
```

Comment: Check your error logs. Are you doing this from a web server?

Comment: @JayBlanchard no xampp on my local computer

Comment: What line in index.php is the line `require("/classes/config.class.php");`?

Comment: @JayBlanchard line 8

Comment: So you're trying to access the variables ___before___ the require line?

Comment: can you show first lines of your `index.php`? error say 'line 2': so when you import `config.class.php`? at line 1, beside `<?php` declaration?

Comment: @MarkBaker no i'm not

Comment: @fusion3k <?php

// Include classes
require("/classes/user.class.php");
require("/classes/password.class.php");

// Include configuration
require("/classes/config.class.php");

echo $servername;
echo $username;
echo $password;
echo $dbname;

Comment: `//` is comment sign: following text is ignored. remove `//` and following text before `require`. Better: carriage return after `<?php` and before `require`

Comment: @fusion3k thanks, now it works!!

Comment: @Jamie you have to remove also other ` // ` in the line!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I write an answer because I can't type carriage returns in comments.

Your code in *index.php* (as your comment above):

```
<?php // Include classes require("/classes/user.class.php"); require("/classes/password.class.php"); // Include configuration require("/classes/config.class.php");
echo $servername;
(...)
```

Double slashes `//` are a comment sign, meaning that all following text it in the same line will be ignored.

I suggest you (also for better code clarity) to edit in this way:

```
<?php
    // Include classes 
    require("/classes/user.class.php");
    require("/classes/password.class.php");
    // Include configuration 
    require("/classes/config.class.php");

    echo $servername;
    (...)
```

---

- Read more about [Comments in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.comments.php)

Answer (score 2):

Config.php File:

```
$database_host = "host";
$database_user = "user";
$database_pass = "pass";
$database_name = "name";
```

Other file you want to call the Config variables from:

```
require_once 'Config.php';
$db = mysqli_connect($database_host, $database_user, $database_pass, $database_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is not working, you might be just in the wrong scope.

It could be that your include is inside a function, then you need to change the setting of your variables to:

```
$GLOBALS['servername'] = 'localhost';
```

or you are using the variable inside a function/class. Then you have to use the global keyword

```
myFunction() {
  //$servername is not defined here
  global $servername;
  // now $servername is defined and the global var is used
}
```

But I think you should do something much more usefull: Using Constants.

```
define('SERVERNAME','localhost');
```

And later get the constant (In ANY scope):

```
echo SERVERNAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check if you are trying to use the variables before including it.

Also check if the file is correctly included ( `require();` in php tags and not out commented ( `//require` ))